# Link custom shared library to binary if more than one copy is present using cmake

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I am linking my local libssl.so and libcrypto.so files to my binary on ubuntu environment. I have these .so files in my project folder `${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH}`.
And same files present in path `"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"` also which were installed before.

But after compilation, i did ldd on binary. But its always showing "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" as link path.

```
ldd rtcc
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdf36b6000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f91ce927000)
libboost_system.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f91ce723000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f91ce440000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f91ce130000)
```

CMakeList.txt

```
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${RTCC_SOURCE_DIR}/libs)
find_library(SSL_LIB NAMES "libssl.so" PATHS ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH})
find_library(CRYPTO_LIB NAMES "libcrypto.so" PATHS ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH})

#Tried with NO_DEFAULT_PATH also, but didn't work
#find_library(SSL_LIB NAMES "libssl.so" PATHS ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
#find_library(CRYPTO_LIB NAMES "libcrypto.so" PATHS ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

target_link_libraries (rtcc
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${SSL_LIB}
    ${CRYPTO_LIB}
)

install(TARGETS rtcc DESTINATION bin
    PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
)
```

I need to link the shares objets which are present in my project. Could you please help me in resolving this issue.

After Some suggestions:
CMakefile.txt

```
# use, i.e. don't skip the full RPATH for the build tree
SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)

# when building, don't use the install RPATH already
# (but later on when installing)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)

# the RPATH to be used when installing
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${FCL_SOURCE_DIR}/libs")

# don't add the automatically determined parts of the RPATH
# which point to directories outside the build tree to the install RPATH
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH FALSE)


target_link_libraries (rtcc
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${FCL_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libssl.so
    ${FCL_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libcrypto.so
)

install(TARGETS rtcc DESTINATION bin
    PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
)
```

Comment: What is intention of `find_library` calls, if you don't use their results? (Variables `SSL_LIB` and `CRYPTO_LIB`). By default, **installed** library lost their *RPATH* adjustments: the library knows *only names* of libraries it linked with, not their paths. See https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling for more info.

Comment: sorry.. I edited now.. I am trying to link my custom libraries, still its taking the global path.

Comment: As @Tsyvarev suggested set RPATH for your library. Particularly you need to use [CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH.html). Check [this article](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling) to get the whole idea

Comment: The whole point of ELF shared object linking is that shared libraries are recorded by their SONAMEs and upon executable loading those sonames are resolved using _current_ ld settings. You may adjust these settings system-wide in `/etc/ld.so.conf`, or if you need to override shared libraries just for a single launch you may use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I have done the things by following your links. Still ldd is showing global links. Please check the CMakeFile with new changes in above section.

Comment: Hmm, accoring to [linker's man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) *RPATH* is prioritized to everything except *LD_LIBRARY_PATH* environment variable. Check that given variable is not set in your case.